# AND condition with null result

Tags: sql, oracle

The code below contains multi where conditions

```
select SUM(COMMONSPEC.DISBURSE_AMT)
  from spec_gt1 COMMONSPEC
  where COMMONSPEC.instance_code_1 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_2 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_3 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_4 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_5 = 3;
```

which one of the condition gives null, hence while the query with **AND** condition will give null while with **OR** condition gives Different result. how can i achieve without writing subquery. Is there is any way

Comment: Not at all clear to me what you're asking, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AND and OR Operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-and-or-clauses.htm)

```
First of all you have to know about what is AND and OR?
When AND is placed the all columns values are match to 3.
```

**Example:**

```
where COMMONSPEC.instance_code_1 = 3
  AND COMMONSPEC.instance_code_2 = 3
  AND COMMONSPEC.instance_code_3 = 3
  AND COMMONSPEC.instance_code_4 = 3
  AND COMMONSPEC.instance_code_5 = 3;
```

AND

```
When OR is placed if any one column value is match to 3 
then it will show the record.
```

**Example:**

```
where COMMONSPEC.instance_code_1 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_2 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_3 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_4 = 3
  OR COMMONSPEC.instance_code_5 = 3;
```

Comment: only with the first condition gives the expected value and only with the second condition gives null. while combining both with AND gives null but with OR gives different value. I hope you understand

Comment: @Sudharsanan ok, can you please post your http://sqlfiddle.com/ link having scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can try `And` with `is Not null`

```
select SUM(COMMONSPEC.DISBURSE_AMT)
         from spec_gt1 COMMONSPEC
        where (COMMONSPEC.instance_code_1 =
             3 and COMMONSPEC.instance_code_1 is not null)
          OR (COMMONSPEC.instance_code_2 =
              3 and COMMONSPEC.instance_code_2 is not null)
          OR (COMMONSPEC.instance_code_3 =
              3 and COMMONSPEC.instance_code_3 is not null)
          OR (COMMONSPEC.instance_code_4 =
              3 and COMMONSPEC.instance_code_4 is not null)
          OR (COMMONSPEC.instance_code_5 =
              3 and COMMONSPEC.instance_code_5 is not null)
```

Comment: @Sudharsanan = place braces and try

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT
          SUM ( DISBURSE_AMT )
    FROM
          SPEC_GT1
    WHERE
          COALESCE ( INSTANCE_CODE_1,
                   INSTANCE_CODE_2,
                   INSTANCE_CODE_3,
                   INSTANCE_CODE_4,
                   INSTANCE_CODE_5 ) = 3;
```

You can try this sample:

```
WITH SPEC_GT1
    AS (SELECT
             1 AS DISBURSE_AMT,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_1,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_2,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_3,
             NULL AS INSTANCE_CODE_4,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_5
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             2 AS DISBURSE_AMT,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_1,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_2,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_3,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_4,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_5
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             3 AS DISBURSE_AMT,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_1,
             NULL AS INSTANCE_CODE_2,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_3,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_4,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_5
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             4 AS DISBURSE_AMT,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_1,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_2,
             2 AS INSTANCE_CODE_3,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_4,
             3 AS INSTANCE_CODE_5
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      SUM ( DISBURSE_AMT )
FROM
      SPEC_GT1
WHERE
      COALESCE ( INSTANCE_CODE_1,
               INSTANCE_CODE_2,
               INSTANCE_CODE_3,
               INSTANCE_CODE_4,
               INSTANCE_CODE_5 ) = 3
```